# How should I write a proper Switch statement so all objects don't Instantiate at once?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have resources loading when a specific function is called. However all of the objects are being Instantiated and not just the specific one I need. I would like some help writing a proper switch statement.

Here is my code.

```
   if (File.Exists(objPath) == Resources.Load("BlueCube"))
    {
        //FileUtil.CopyFileOrDirectory(objPath, savePath);
    GameObject instance = Instantiate(Resources.Load("BlueCube", typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;
    }

    if (File.Exists(objPath) == Resources.Load("RedCube"))
    {

    GameObject instance = Instantiate(Resources.Load("RedCube", typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;

    }

    if (File.Exists(objPath) == Resources.Load("GreenCube"))
    {
    GameObject instance = Instantiate(Resources.Load("GreenCube", typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;
    }
    if (File.Exists(objPath) == Resources.Load("PurpleCube"))
    {
    GameObject instance = Instantiate(Resources.Load("PurpleCube", typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;
    }
```

Comment: "when a specific function is called." where is this specific function? the presented critiria here is base on the existence of files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the if statements you are trying to compare a boolean result from File.Exists(objPath) with an object type from Resources.Load("Any").

File.Exists(string path) just says if the file exists.

Resources.Load("AnyCube") returns a GameObject in the context.

What filenames are passed through objPath? Do you have some sample names? Then it is easier to show a real switch case here.

I can imagine that the file names have the name that should be loaded here as a resource. Then you could solve that with a conditional switch.

```
GameObject instance;
    switch (objPath)
    { 
         case string op when op.Contains("BlueCube"):
             instance = Instantiate(Resources.Load("BlueCube", typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;
             break;
         case string op when op.Contains("RedCube"):
             instance = Instantiate(Resources.Load("RedCube", typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;
             break;
         case string op when op.Contains("GreenCube"):
             instance = Instantiate(Resources.Load("GreenCube", typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;
             break;
    }
```

But a switch case can be used with the scope, but if more different game objects are loaded, then it is better to start with an open-close principle.

Comment: Thank you so much you helped me solve it.  Blessings to you and your family.

Answer (score 0):

well ... `File.Exists(objPath)` returns a `bool` and `Resources.Load("BlueCube")` returns the loaded `UnityEngine.Object` which has an implicit conversion to `bool`

=> All your `if` conditions can be `true` at the same time

Comment: Yes I'm aware of this. I'm not able to write the proper switch statement that would prevent this from happening. Can you help?

Comment: @HamJovante not really without knowing what exact you are expecting the code to do

Answer (score 0):

For a `switch-case` to work, you need to have something you can check for different cases. In your case, it seems you want to instantiate cubes of different colors. Introducing an `enum` can help with readability and extensibility.

Create a new enum that includes all your colors, you can easily add new colors later. Next, instead of using `objectPath`, you want to use that enum.

Say your function currently looks like this:

`private void InstantiateCubeAtPath(string objPath)`

You want to change it to:

`private void InstantiateCubeWithColor(CubeColor CubeColor.green)`or whatever Color you want. You also have to need to add the information about its Color to each cube.

In your `switch case` you now check for CubeColor and proceed from there.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you! Blessing to you and your family!